# Is there any way to remove skipped tests in allure report in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rspec, allure

Currently skipped tests are shown in Allure report and percentage is calculated based on skipped report as well ? Is there any way skipped tests can be removed from allure report ? We are currently using latest [allure-ruby](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-ruby) version

Answer (score 0):

I have a work around for this. Once the result folder is generated. I will run the script to remove `skipped` test on the `.json` file. After this script run the `allure` report generation command.

````
ls
for D in *;
do
CREDENTIALS=$(jq -c '. | .status' $D)
a=$CREDENTIALS
b='"skipped"'
if [[ $a == $b ]]
then
rm $D
fi
done
ls```
````

Answer (score 0):

We can do a batch script command to clear the skipped transactions this will be a double work but it will do the job

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).